# How do I create a bar chart instead of line chart with HighCharts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm using DotNetHighCharts to make HighChart's charts. This example I found makes a line chart of monthly data:

```
        Highcharts monthlyChart = new Highcharts("chart")
        .SetXAxis(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.XAxis
        {
            Categories =
                new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }

        })
        .SetSeries(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series
        {
            Data = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(new object[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 60, 14, 72, 30, 35, 10, 20, 25 })
        });
```

I tried `new HighCharts("bar")` but it still makes a line chart.

Comment: Are you able to solve your question with the answer described below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Highcharts using following command using Package manager console of Visual Studio, this install new version of `DotNet.Highcharts` - `4.0.0`

```
Install-Package DotNet.Highcharts
```

Then I Created following view (Don't forget to include JS Files).

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample";
}
@using DotNet.Highcharts;
@using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
@using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@{
    Highcharts chrt = new Highcharts("chart")
                    .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" } })
                    .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Sales" } })
                    .SetSeries(new Series { Data = new Data(new object[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 60, 14, 72, 30, 35, 10, 20 }), Name = "Sales" })
                    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Sales Data" })
                    .InitChart(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart { DefaultSeriesType = DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.ChartTypes.Column });
}

@(chrt)
```

And the output was -

[image]

Samples for Highcharts can be downloaded from [here](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/121251).